# Why Xcode or iOS render my icon with ugly corners?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

PLease tell me how can I create app icon for iOS 7 with perfect quality?

Now my two app icons have black artifacts on corners..

[image: my two app icons have black artifacts on corners]

Original iPad desktop icon for retina 144x144px without artifacts

[image: Original iPad desktop icon for retina 144x144px without artifacts]

I also check "iOS icon is pre-rendered"

[image: xcode appicon screenshot]

What I'am doing wrong? Why Xcode or iOS render my icon with ugly corners?

Please, help..

Comment: When you created that icon using the Photoshop template, did you export it with the corning already created? Do it without.

Comment: Thanks, squared icon works perfect without ugly corners!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally make my icons square in the first place and then let Xcode handle the curved corners. That way you don't end up with ugly curved black lines.

Comment: Thanks, squared icon works perfect without ugly corners!

Comment: This is true, I tried this earlier and it worked for me too, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your red background is to big, when re-rendering the corners some of the red comes inside the app icon, it looks dark because it is mixed up with the blue.
Create a completely squared app icon, xcode will do the rest and it won't look screwed.
(remove the red background)

Comment: Thanks, squared icon works perfect without ugly corners! Red background was for example :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your app icon's corner radius and apple's standard corner radius are mismatching. So they filling the gap with black backgound. I suggest you to make a squred icon  and dont check iOS icon is pre-rendered unless there is a particular requirement. Another solution is to adjust the icon with some image editor. May be adjusting your corner radius will help you.

Comment: Thanks, squared icon works perfect without ugly corners!